# Extend a gem module with an instance method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im trying to extend a InstanceMethods of a gem (Globalize)

```
module Globalize
  module ActiveRecord
    module InstanceMethods 
      def foo
        puts "Bar!"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However, this overwrites the existing instance methods of Globalize.

What is the correct way of giving a previously declared module additional instance methods?

Update:
Trying to require them doesnt seem to work either:

```
module Globalize
  require 'globalize'
  module ActiveRecord
    require 'globalize/active_record'
    module InstanceMethods
      require 'globalize/active_record/instance_methods'
      def foo
        puts "Bar!"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Update: By using answer provided by roxxypoxxy I can extend the instance methods by adding his answer to a initializer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
Globalize::ActiveRecord::InstanceMethods.class_eval do
    # patch methods
end
```

Comment: where would i put this? In an initilizer?

Comment: Yeah. You can make a .rb file at config/initializers/  
or
you should be able to put it in lib folder also

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to be sure you require the module before monkeypatching it; if it is relying on the autoloader to load those files, then defining them will prevent the autoloader from attempting to require them. Globalize is indeed relying on the autoloader, as [seen here](https://github.com/globalize/globalize/blob/master/lib/globalize/active_record.rb).

To fix it, explicitly require those modules before patching them:

```
 require 'globalize'
 require 'globalize/active_record'
 require 'globalize/active_record/instance_methods'

 # Patch your stuff here.
```

Comment: Hmm, didnt get it to work. perhaps i missplaces them?

Comment: Try ensuring that the module exists and has the methods you are interested in before you patch it. What behavior are you seeing?

Comment: InstanceMethods, such as translated_attributes gives "undefined method `translated_attributes'". But my foo method is there.